# One more colorbar at each loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a little problem and I don't find a solution for the moment. I have a script which makes lots of figures in a loop. I loop on the first file, make 10 figures, then I take the second file etc ...

All seems to work, but in my last figure, I get one color bar, then 2 color bars after the second loop, then 3 etc ... This problem appears only in my last plot.

Do you have any idea on this kind of problem ?

This is the end of my loop with the last plot :

```
fig = plt.gcf()

SN_map_final = (S_N_map - mean_SN) / sigma_SN

fig12 = plt.figure(12)
fig_SN_final = plt.imshow(SN_map_final)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label(r'Signal to Noise (significance $\sigma$)')
plt.xlabel('X (arcmin)')
plt.ylabel('Y (arcmin)')
plt.title('Signal to Noise map')

fig12 = plt.savefig(outname12)
```

Thank you if you have a way to resolve this problem ;)

**SOLUTION :**

I added :

```
plt.clf()
```

at the end of my loop and it seems to work

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're creating the colorbar in a loop. So each time you run the loop, it creates a new one.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Yes I assume, that's why I ask question lol

Comment: Okay, so don't create the bar in the loop. I'm confused what your issue is.

Comment: You can clear your plot with `plt.clf()`. Note that all axis definitions etc. are reset.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem ..

Comment: I added `plt.clf()` at the end. It works thanks. Down vote was not obligatory ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just modified your code to plot some image, and then I tested it. The problem is that you are not clearing properly your figure once you save it. So, every time you call plt it get the current figure (which has some plot already) and overlap the new one. If you clear the Figure after saving it, then the problem is solved:

```
im = np.random.rand(100,100)

for i in xrange(10):
    fig12 = plt.figure(12)
    fig_SN_final = plt.imshow(im)
    cbar = plt.colorbar()
    cbar.set_label(r'Signal to Noise (significance $\sigma$)')
    plt.xlabel('X (arcmin)')
    plt.ylabel('Y (arcmin)')
    plt.title('Signal to Noise map')
    plt.savefig(str('%03d'%i)+'.png')
    plt.clf()
```

I tested previous example and does work for me.